# Why find(element).click uses max_wait_time instead of the specified wait:0 if the element is not clickable?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

Background: checking if element is clickable (I expect it to be not clickable, I want to assert this) without waiting. 
find().click uses Capybara.max_wait_time and then returns exception:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError Exception: unknown error: Element <input type="text" class="form-control floatingInput" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your first name" aria-label="First Name" value="Lynn"> is not clickable at point (415, 301). Other element would receive the click: <div class="Checkout__overlay__1cqyM"></div>
```

instead of returning exception instantly.

Exact line of code that waits when it should not in my view. This waits max_wait_time (e. g. 20 seconds) if the element is not clickable (hidden by overlay as expected). It is clear that I supplied wait: 0

`find(checkout.ship_first_name.path, wait: 0).click`

It appears that either there is a different timeout for exception, or  #click uses it's own timeout, however #click does not take arguments AFAIK.

Note 1

find(element, wait: 0) works properly by itself, as I'm using it in if/else blocks and there is no unnecessary wait just like specified.

Note 2

`#visible?` does not work in this case as the element is visible, but behind a transparent grey overlay. I need to verify it's not clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` does take a few options (modifier keys to be held down when clicking, click offset, and wait/retry time) so to do what you're trying to do would be

```
find(checkout.ship_first_name.path, wait: 0).click(wait: 0)
```

or

```
using_wait_time(0) do # may need to be page.using_wait_time(0) depending on your setup
  find(checkout.ship_first_name.path).click
end
```

However from Capybara 3.20+ (assuming you are using Chrome or Firefox) you could also just do

```
find(checkout.ship_first_name.path).obscured?
```

to find out whether it is on the page but obscured from being clicked. If you are setting an expectation that it should be obscured then you would do

```
expect(page).to have_css(checkout.ship_first_name.path, obscured: true)
```

Comment: `page.using_wait_time(0) { find(element).click }` solved it!

Im using this code in custom expectations. To assert if element is visible or not, present or not, behind an overlay (thus unclickable).


```
  def expect_to_be_non_selectable
    begin
      page.using_wait_time(0) { find(@type, @path).click }
    rescue => error
      error.message
    else
      raise "Error: element can be selected when it shouldn't.\n It should should be notvisible, hidden behind overlay or simply not present. \n #{@path}"
    end
  end
```